# How to analyze time series data and mark if single data is seasonal or not seasonal

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, python, modeling

[image: dataset]

I have data set as shown above. It has daily sales data for 4 different product for almost a year. I aggregated the sales of product for each day into the following format:

[image: this]

I plotted sales of 4 product as per date and got this: [image: plot]

From the plot, it is clear that there is some recurring pattern (fall during sept and raise in common months) in purchase behavior. I want to know how to pin point a single data and classify the sales seasonal or non seasonal.

Comment: If you search for time series decomposition, you can find a lot of R packages and posts with example to do this.

Comment: if you want seasonality of months you should have more than 1 year of data.

Comment: No, I want to capture the seasonality seen in the plot. it represents daily sales.

Comment: Udhai,  please explain what you mean by "seasonality."  Your post suggests you are trying to detect patterns that might recur from year to year and in that sense @user3201928 is absolutely correct: you haven't any hope of succeeding with just one year's worth of data.  In particular, what do you mean by "common months"?

Comment: Also, concerning the title: what do you mean by "single data" and, given that this phrase suggests you might be considering a subset of your time series, could you explain what it might mean for this subset to be "seasonal" but the rest of the series not to be?

Comment: By seasonality I meant pattern in sales ideally calendar effect. I am trying to detect if there is pattern in sales for the four products. The plot represents daily sales of four product and they follow similar sales pattern for some months. Finally I want to use the information and mark every single data if the sale was due to seasonal effect(pattern found in other products) or non seasonal. I will add this info in question as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to identify a series as having "seasonality" one needs to consider both the presence of SARIMA structure and/or seasonal dummies. To do so one needs to identify and adjust for anomalies. To do so one needs to identify and adjust for possible power transforms or to use weighted least squares.To do so one needs to identify possible level/step shifts and/or possible time trends. To do so one needs to have an observation for each type of series for each day.

If you only have 1 year of daily data, that is not enough to substantiate a seasonal component other than a daily seasonal effect or a possible week-in-the-month effect or a possible day-in=the-month effect.

https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf suggests the general model. If you don't have any user-specified X's things are simpler.

Comment: From the plot it is clear that there is some recurring pattern(fall during sept and raise in common months) in purchase behavior. I want to know how to pin point a single data and classify the sales seasonal or non seasonal.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a nested test using (generalized) linear models or ANOVA equivalently.

Derive season as a fixed effect. Then fit the linear regression model adjusting for categorical season as a dummy variable with 3 levels. Perform the 3-degree of freedom nested test against the intercept-only model. If the result is statistically significant, conclude that mean # of sales differs by season.

To account for the count structure of the outcome, you could consider a quasipoisson model.